# Rails 4 form validate regex (title, body)

Tags: regex, forms, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

trying to validate title and body of micropost form. I have been trying to figure this out for a day now. It's getting personal... :)

I am new to both Rails (1.5month) and regex (1day)

For title: I want to allow UTF-8 characters and spaces
For body: I want to allow UTF-8 chars, spaces and punctuation.

http://rubular.com/ (ruby v 2.1.5) tells me this is going to be OK:

```
/[[:space:]]*[[:alpha:]]*/
/[[:alpha:]]*[[:space:]]*/
```

But when I try this:

```
validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 60 }, format: { with: /[[:alpha:]]*[[:space:]]*/, message: "only letters" }
```

It lets digits and chars like these +!%/=( to slip through.

The following fails too. It doesn't allow me spaces - at least it raises error when I include digits or other strange characters:

```
format: { with: /\A[[:alpha:]]*[[:space:]]*\z/, message: "only letters" }
```

I also tried to make something like this but that makes no difference, fails too:

```
REGEX = ........
format: { with: REGEX, message: "only letters" }
```

These fail too:

```
format: { with: /\A[\p{L}\ ]\z/
format: { with: /[\p{L}\ ]/
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT
my model idea.rb

```
class Idea < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
has_many :tags, through: :taggings
attr_reader :tag_tokens
acts_as_likeable
has_many :likes, foreign_key: :likeable_id
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
validates :user_id, presence: true
validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 60 }, format: { with: /[[:alpha:]]|[[:space:]]/, message: 'only letters'}
validates :intro, presence: true, length: { minimum: 60, maximum: 160 }
validates :tag_ids, presence: true
....
private
def idea_params
params.require(:idea).permit(:title, :intro, :content, :user_id, :name)
end
end
```

This doesn't allow numbers in the beginning but allows them anywhere else:

```
validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 60 }, format: { with: /\A[[:alpha:]]|[[:space:]]\z/, message: 'only letters'}
```

This doesn't allow space:

```
/\A([[:alpha:]]|[[:space:]]+)\z/
```

This allows space but number too:

```
/([[:alpha:]]|[[:space:]]+)/
```

accepts numbers too:

/(\p{L} +)/
   /[\p{L}\s]+/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
/\A[\p{L}\s]+\z/
```

This accepts any unicode (UTF-8) letter and any number of space but no digit or other character (for example: %/=()+!) anywhere in a word or by itself.

Finally... :)

Answer (score 0):

I took information about regexp for utf-8 chars from [Ruby language documentation site.](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/regexp_rdoc.html)

Working for me

```
# /[[:alpha:]]|[[:space:]]/
class Selection
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  validates :name, presence: true, format: { with: /[[:alpha:]]|[[:space:]]/, message: 'only letters'}
end
```

But when you use **presence** option it means that you cannot have only spaces.

You can test with

> **~**

Comment: **Thanks** for this @farhatmihalko unfortunately having this in my modell still doesn't work: validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 10, maximum: 60 }, format: { with: /[[:alpha:]]|[[:space:]]/, message: 'only letters'} But do you recon to put all the above code you wrote in my modell? That would raise other questions?: What would I do with my original line? Where does your piece of code go in the modell? And I have sqlite in dev and postgredb in production - how would I change your second line then?

Comment: @Zsolt can you provide please your model

Comment: Sure @farhatmihalko edited the original question, added the model.